# dojo query to return georss:point values in XML

Tags: xml, dojo

I have xml as follows:

```
<item>
<title>HOUSE FIRE (NO INJURIES) - MONASH</title>
<link>http://esa.act.gov.au/feeds/currentincidents.xml</link>
<description>
Incident: HOUSE FIRE (NO INJURIES)
</description>
<guid>006782-03022013</guid>
<pubDate>04 Feb 2013 15:43:56 EST</pubDate>
<georss:point>-35.4165878527591 149.095271972785</georss:point>
</item>
```

What is the dojo.query on a DOM object to return the lat and long values of the georss:point element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember having a similar problem a few months ago, so thought I'd give this a go.  The problem is with the XML namespaced element (**<georss:point>**), finding the other elements is simple.

According to the [CSS3 Selector spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#typenmsp), namespaced elements can be selected using the **|** symbol. So, **georss|point**, should be the correct selector.  However, you need to have previously declared this namespace to the selector engine.  I have no idea how to do this with [dojo/query](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/query.html).

A workaround is to use ***** to signify any namespace; hence, ***|point**, will work.  However, it will find any point element of any namespace within the document.  In most cases this will not be a problem.

Eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "dojo/query",
        "dojo/request",
        "dojo/dom-attr"
    ], function($, request, domAttr){
        request("test.xml", {
            "preventCache": true,
            "handleAs": "xml"
        }).then(function(xmldom){
            var georss = $("*|point", xmldom.documentElement);
            if(georss.length > 0){ // ensure we have our element
                console.log("georss:point", georss[0]); // Test code
                var latLng = domAttr.get(georss[0], "innerHTML").split(" ");
            }

        }, function(err){
            console.error(err);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If getting all namespaces causes problems then you could just filter the nodes according to their **namespaceURI** attribute.

It might be that someone out there knows how to pass a namespace to dojo/query, that would make it a lot better.  It ought to be a feature of the selector engine if Dojo have not already included it.

**Edit:** It appears that you do not need the ***|point** in either Chrome, Firefox or Opera, **point** will suffice. However, this will not work in Internet Explorer (I've tested in IE8, unsure of later versions).  In IE, the namespace selector is required.

Comment: Edited my answer to include note about different browser rules.  After reading your comment, I decided to retest my code and found you were right!  I was then a bit confused as to why I'd originally followed this route.  Looks like Internet Explorer is the odd one out again.  I don't have access to IE9/IE10, it could be that these work the same as the others.